# ESB WSO2 - Connecting to a local MySQL database ["Registry entry defined with key: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver not found"]

Tags: mysql, wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-micro-integrator, wso2-esb

First of all I want to say that I'm a beginner with ESB WSO2.

I want to connect to a MySQL DataBase and I get this error:
"Error DB Mediator datasource: null.Registry entry defined with key: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver not found."
"DataSource: null was not initialized for given JNDI properties"

This is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api context="/api/dbtask" name="api.dbtask" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <resource methods="GET">
        <inSequence>
            <dblookup>
                <connection>
                    <pool>
                        <driver key="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
                        <url key="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/utilizatori"/>
                        <user key="root"/>
                        <password key="1234"/>
                    </pool>
                </connection>
                <statement>
                    <sql><![CDATA[SELECT * FROM people WHERE id=1;]]></sql>
                    <parameter expression="//m0:getQuote/m0:request/m0:symbol" type="VARCHAR" xmlns:m0="https://services.samples"/>
                    <result column="nume" name="nume"/>
                </statement>
            </dblookup>
            <!--
            <log level="custom">
                    <property name="ID" expression="get-property('id')" />
                    <property name="NAME" expression="get-property('nume')" />
                    <property name="AGE" expression="get-property('varsta')" />
            </log>
                -->
            <respond/>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence/>
        <faultSequence/>
    </resource>
</api>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an issue with the connection pool you have added. The above format is used to get the configuration values from the registry [1],[2]. If you want to define the connection pool inline you need to use the following format [3].

```
<dblookup xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <connection>
        <pool>
            <driver>org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver</driver>
            <url>jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/esbdb;create=false</url>
            <user>esb</user>
            <password>esb</password>
        </pool>
    </connection>
    <statement>
        <sql><![CDATA[select * from company where name =?]]></sql>
        <parameter expression="//m0:getQuote/m0:request/m0:symbol" type="VARCHAR" xmlns:m0="http://services.samples/xsd"/>
        <result column="id" name="company_id"/>
    </statement>
</dblookup>
```

[1]-https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI640/Managing+the+Registry

[2]-https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/7.2.0/micro-integrator/references/mediators/dBLookup-Mediator/#connection-pool-configurations

[3]-https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/7.2.0/micro-integrator/references/mediators/dBLookup-Mediator/#example

Comment: I just added my connection in the Enterprise Integrator here ("Home  > Configure  > Datasources") and then changed my code into:
                    <pool>
                     <dsName>MySQL</dsName>
                    </pool> and it worked